# Why do these menu items disappear/reappear in Android Studio Beta?

Tags: android, cordova

In some cases, I can click on the menu item Android in Tools > Android, and at other times it is completely missing.

In some cases, I can click on Build > Generate Signed APK... and sometimes it is grayed out.

I suspect the appearances are contextual, based on something else happening first, but I have no idea what that is.

My development environment:

Mac OS X 10.9.5 on latest Mac Mini
Cordova CLI 3.6.3 (cordova, not phonegap)
APIs 19 & 20 installed

Answer (score 0):

1. Choosing Opening Screen's Import Project... (same as File > Import Project...) for a Cordova project which has never been opened in Android Studio before does not display these menu items. It preserves the Cordova folder structure.
2. Choosing Opening Screen's New Project... (same as File > New Project...) DOES display these menu items. It creates a Gradle folder structure - not useful for cross-platform use.
3. Choosing Opening Screen's Open Project... (same as File > Open) for a Cordova project which has never been opened in Android Studio before DOES display these menu items. It preserves the Cordova folder structure. A message says that a framework was detected. Click on Configure then OK in the Setup Framework popup. Then the missing menu items display. **If we do not click on the Configure link, then the menu items will not appear.**